# fitting a multimode distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to find out the no of the modes of a multimodal distribution in python. I have a distribution like below

```
a=np.array([10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5,14,14.5,15,15.5,16,16.5,17,17.5,18,18.5,19,19.5,20,20.5,21,21.5,22])
b=np.array([0,0,0,0,5,7,8,10,12,25,20,18,10,7,6,8,9,15,20,40,35,25,15,8,7])
```

where `b` is the frequency of `a` and `a` is the mid point of each diameter.

Now my aim is to fit this distribution (multi-mode) and to get the fitted parameter. This data has two modes so after fitting I also want to know the fraction corresponding to each fitting also
I am looking for suggestions. Thanks in advance.